# Should we close this question about "hard martial arts"?

Tags: discussion

[Styles associated with Hard style martial arts?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9512/styles-associated-with-hard-style-martial-arts)

To me, this question fails on two points. First of all, it's got two separate questions, what martial arts styles are "hard" and how to figure out if a Krav Maga class is authentic. Secondly, it's got an unhelpful definition of "hard" that has apparently provoked a decent amount of rancor over the idea of "martial arts focused on severely injuring others". However, since I've voted to close, it's gained a 500 point bounty.

What do people think? Is this a good question for the site?

Comment: Yep, I'm with you on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's on-topic.

### Definitions

For the purposes of asking a question, the asker should be able to define terms. This is part of allowing people of all knowledge and skill levels to participate; you cannot expect novices to use the same language as experts. Nowhere are you obligated to continue using the asker's definition, although it might be helpful to answer their question.

### Multiple questions

The question is basically about finding a quality, very aggressive martial art that may or may not be Krav Maga. I think this falls under our recommendation question type. Although it can produce a list of answers, this question has very definite criteria about how to restrict that list and prioritize one answer (style) over another.

### Cultural bias

In general, I think there is a problem on this site with people thinking only in the context of the martial art they train. If someone wants to ask questions about martial arts for soldiers, there should not inherently be a problem with this.

Comment: {nods} Perhaps if the last part was rephrased to "How can I determine if a given school, such as a Krav Maga school, is teaching 'hard style' martial arts?"